# ODBC connection to Azure using ActiveDirectoryInteractive

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, odbc

I am connecting to an Azure SQL database using `pyodbc`. We have multi-factor authentication enabled, so I am using `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` authentication. We also use single sign-on for Windows.

My code is as follows:

```
import pyodbc

driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
server = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
authentication = 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER=' + driver + ';' +
    'SERVER=' + server + ';' +
    'DATABASE=' + database + ';' +
    'UID=' + username + ';' +
    'AUTHENTICATION=' + authentication + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

When I run the script I get pop-ups to submit my password and MFA details. But the connection works whether I fill in these details or just close the prompts - suggesting that single sign-on is working successfully. So why am I getting the password and MFA pop-ups - and how can I suppress them?

Comment: You can disable MFA in the portal.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhegz.png

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks. Would that disable it across Office 365? (I don't currently have access to the portal to test it.) I can see our IT function having a problem with it if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will disable it in Office 365, but if you want to disable MFA for users in Azure ad, I think the easiest way is to disable it directly in the portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have access to the Portal, I think that's going to disable MFA from our accounts in general not just for our Azure SQL Database, which isn't a viable option. I just want to prevent the unnecessary authentication pop-ups when connecting to our database using ODBC, not turn off MFA.